# Problema de concurrencia al modificar un dato de una lista que soporta sincronización

Tags: c#, hilos

Buen día. Espero que se encuentren bien, estoy intentando hacer una prueba unitaria para probar una estructura de datos (Wrapper) que es **"thread safe"**, primero hice una prueba donde 10 hilos accedían y añadían información para ver si había concurrencia, primero probé una lista sin sincronización, en este caso, lo lógico es que hubiera problema de concurrencia, efectivamente, lo había, apliqué una lista sincronizada y problema resuelto, acá dejo el código de la prueba (Si creen que se puede mejorar, sería excelente un aporte)

**Test Case:**

```
        //Arrange
        SortedList<int> list = new();
        var synchronizedList = list.Synchronized();
        var expected = new SortedList<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int len = 10;
        ParallelOptions options = new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = len
        };

        //Act
        Parallel.For(0, len, options, synchronizedList.Add);

        //Asserts
        Assert.Equal(len, list.Count);
        Assert.Equal(expected, list);
```

En este caso no hubo ningún problema, todo funcionó como debería de ser, el problema surge cuando quiero hacer el típico ejemplo de concurrencia, donde se crean N hilos y aumentan N veces, en este ejemplo si o si debe de haber concurrencia, así que preparé un pequeño caso de prueba para probar que soportase dicho problema, este es el código:

**Test Case 2:**

```
        //Arrange
        SortedList<int> list = new()
        {
            0
        };
        var synchronizedList = list.Synchronized();
        int len = 2, maxIter = 1;
        ParallelOptions options = new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = len
        };

        //Act
        Parallel.For(0, len, options, i =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j != maxIter; ++j)
            {
                synchronizedList[0]++;
            }
        });

        //Asserts
        Assert.Equal(maxIter * len, list[0]);
```

Cuando pruebo el caso de prueba, por una extraña razón, el resultado esperado era 2 (yo probé por primera vez 10000 iteraciones, por lo tanto y 10 hilos) pero me estaba dando 1, extrañado fui a ver el código del problema y no vi ninguno, acá adjunto el código del indexador de la clase Wrapper:

**Indexador:**

```
public T this[int index] 
            {
                get
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        return _sortedList[index];
                    }
                }
                set
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        _sortedList[index] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Como podemos ver, tenemos el lock, por lo tanto, accede de manera segura, de hecho, hice una prueba de debug y justamente así si pasa la prueba, luego de esto, fui al código donde inicializo el _lock.

**Constructor:**

```
internal SynchronizedSortedList(SortedList<T> sortedList)
{
      _sortedList = sortedList;
      _lock = _sortedList.SyncRoot;
}
```

Luego de ver que todo estaba "bien", voy al método get de **SyncRoot** de la clase **SortedList**.

**SyncRoot:**

```
public object SyncRoot
{
     get
     {
           if (_syncRoot == null)
           {
               Interlocked.CompareExchange<object>(ref _syncRoot, new object(), null);
           }
           return _syncRoot;
     }
}
```

En teoría, todo está bien, de hecho, fui a revisar el código fuente de una versión muy anterior de la clase **List** y vi que lo tenía igual, por lo tanto, no debería de haber problemas, por último, mostraré el método **Synchronized**.

**Synchronized:**

```
public ISortedList<T> Synchronized()
{
   return new SynchronizedSortedList(this);
}
```

Una forma de arreglarlo es obvia, sería de la siguiente manera:

```
        //Arrange
        SortedList<int> list = new()
        {
            0
        };
        var synchronizedList = list.Synchronized();
        int len = 2, maxIter = 1;
        ParallelOptions options = new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = len
        };

        //Act
        Parallel.For(0, len, options, i =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j != maxIter; ++j)
            {
                lock(list.SyncRoot)
                {
                   synchronizedList[0]++;
                }
            }
        });

        //Asserts
        Assert.Equal(maxIter * len, list[0]);
```

De esta manera funcionaría excelente, pero no es la manera como lo quiero hacer porque este Wrapper ya tiene **locks** que protegen el recurso para que los hilos no accedan y prevenir concurrencia. Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería muchísimo porque estoy desde ayer con este problema y no me se ocurre casi nada. Saludos.

Comment: Tu código no es completo. Yo copie y pegué y `SortedList` tiene un error, así que supongo que es de otra dll y `Assert` parece que es una librería de 3ros

Comment: @Yussef SortedList es una implementación creada por mí, el Wrapper igual, la cree para hacer que SortedList tuviera soporte para protección de procesos. El Assert es de la biblioteca de XUnit, de hecho, recalco que estaba haciendo una prueba unitaria.

Comment: Ok. te recomiendo colocar un ejemplo completo, que sea copiar/pegar y compile

Comment: Es un código muy largo, pero puedo dejar el link del github de la 
[prueba de integración](https://github.com/Ts-Pytham/GenericCollectionsExtension/blob/2085d282fd5f0e30ec5683e754c7d042bf5a2597/GenericCollectionsExtension.Tests/List/SortedList/SortedListTests.cs#L248) y acá está el código del [SortedList con el Wrapper](https://github.com/Ts-Pytham/GenericCollectionsExtension/blob/master/GenericCollectionsExtension/List/SortedList/SortedList.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Las preguntas deben tener un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), un código que exponga el problema lo más simple y resumido posible. Realizar una pregunta no es un trabajo sencillo y no tiene porque serlo. En la práctica yo debería copiar y pegar tu código, ejecutarlo y visualizar el problema directamente. El código que tu has publicado en Github tiene demasiado ruido y además a mi me arroja una excepción

Perfectamente tu problema se puede resumir en:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SynchronizedSortedList<int> list = new SynchronizedSortedList<int>(new List<int> { 0 });
        int len =200;
        object ob=new object();
        ParallelOptions options = new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = len
        };

        object obj_lock=new object();
        Parallel.For(0, len, options, i =>
        {
            //lock (obj_lock){
                list[0]++;
            //}
        });

        Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
    }
}

internal class SynchronizedSortedList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _sortedList;
    private readonly object _lock;

    internal SynchronizedSortedList(List<T> sortedList)
    {
        _sortedList = sortedList;
        _lock = new object();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sortedList)
            {
                return _sortedList[index];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_sortedList)
            {
                _sortedList[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**¿Ves como si posible?**

---

2.- Tu problema es que el Get y el Set son elementos separados e independientes, entonces tu tienes esto:

```
list[0]++;
```

Que es lo mismo que:

```
  v--Set    v--Get
list[0] = list[0] + 1;
```

Donde el Get está "lockeado" y el Set también está "lockeado" pero independientemente, por lo que cuando entrar al paralelismo puedes haber ejecutado 3 Get seguidos (por decir un número random) antes de hacer el primer Set

Por eso que esto funciona:

```
lock (obj_lock){
    list[0]++;
}
```

Porque el "lockeo" es a toda la instrucción.

Esto es facilmente demostrable si haces esto:

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Console.Write("GET ");
            return _sortedList[index];
               
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Console.Write("SET ");
            _sortedList[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Verás un resultado parecido a:

```
GET GET GET GET GET GET GET GET SET GET SET GET SET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET GET SET SET GET SET GET SET SET GET SET GET SET SET GET SET GET SET SET GET SET SET GET
```

Y para que funcione como tu esperas debería verse `GET SET GET SET` intercalados

3.- El test no es correcto

Lo que realmente creo es que tu Test es incorrecto, la lógica subyacente no es la adecuada y no prueba nada.

Analiza el siguiente ejemplo, donde he creado una clase envoltorio para los int y he sobrescrito el operador `++`

```js
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SynchronizedSortedList<Numero> list = new SynchronizedSortedList<Numero>(new List<Numero> { new Numero(0) });
        int len =200;
        object ob=new object();
        ParallelOptions options = new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = len
        };

        object obj_lock=new object();
        Parallel.For(0, len, options, i =>
        {
            list[0]++;

        });

        Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
    }
}

internal class SynchronizedSortedList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _sortedList;

    internal SynchronizedSortedList(List<T> sortedList)
    {
        _sortedList = sortedList;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _sortedList[index];
        }
        set
        {
            _sortedList[index] = value;
        }
    }

}
public class Numero
{
    public int numero;
    public Numero(int numero) => this.numero = numero;
    public override string ToString() => numero.ToString();

    public static Numero operator ++(Numero n)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref n.numero);
        return n;
    }

}
```

Este ejemplo da TU resultado esperado, y funciona porque esto

```
list[0]++;
```

No tiene nada que ver con la Lista si no que es con el objeto contenido, es decir la concurrencia no la pruebas con ese trozo, ya que llegado a ese punto ese `list[0]` es el objeto en cuestión y ya la lista no tiene nada que hacer. Por eso lo que debes proteger son los objetos

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, de hecho, la prueba unitaria que hice fue por un error que quería ver, pero sí, no debí de hacerlo, claro, yo quisiera agregar que sucede por el tema de que esa operación en general *list[0]++* no es atómica y claro, como tu mismo dijiste, si descomponemos la operación, hay muchas sub operaciones que se realizan, aunque hay bloqueos en todas esas operaciones, lo que está dentro del setter son operaciones secuenciales y peor aún, se está haciendo una reindexación y como es código que es muy complejo de proteger con un bloqueo, sucede eso, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías probar a utilizar el metodo **Interlocked.Increment**:

```
//Arrange
SortedList<int> list = new SortedList<int> { 0 };
var synchronizedList = list.Synchronized();
int len = 2, maxIter = 1;
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = len
};

//Act
Parallel.For(0, len, options, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j != maxIter; ++j)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref synchronizedList[0]);
    }
});

//Asserts
Assert.Equal(maxIter * len, list[0]);
```

Para que la operación de incremento se realice de manera segura en un entorno concurrente, sin la necesidad de utilizar un lock adicional.

Comment: Claro, esa solución se me ocurrió pero se supone que ese Wrapper internamente tiene un lock en el index para hacer un set y un get, por lo tanto no debería de crear ese interlocked ahí porque cuando muchos procesos acceden al recurso (al index) hay un lock que protege el recurso hasta que un hilo termine de utilizar dicho recurso (así como la exclusión mutua o mutex), el fin de esta prueba de integración es probar que si hay thread safe, si agrego ese Interlocked estoy alterando la prueba. ¡Muchas gracias por comentar!